# Use SVG filter attribute in React.js

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have been researching a bit on data representation with SVG and React and they seem a perfect fit. However SVG is not yet supported in React, and an addon does not exist yet https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2250.

Yet there is some workarounds like using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` for some elements, in my case I cannot find one yet.

I want to use `filter` attribute inside a `circle` svg element. However It gets not rendered into the DOM. Here it is my React Component:

```
class DeviceDot extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { app, idx } = this.props

    return  <circle cx={50 * idx} cy={50 * idx} r='25' filter={`url(#${app})`} fill='mediumorchid' />
  }
}
```

And the filter:

```
class FilterSVG extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { app, idx } = this.props
    const icon = app ? `/api/apps/${app}/logo` : '/img/dflt.png'

    return (
      <filter id={app || 'default'} x='0%' y='0%' width='100%' height='100%'>
        <feImage xlinkHref={icon} />
      </filter>
    )
  }
}
```

However I cannot use dangerouslySetInnerHTML without wrapping this component, which I want to reuse as is (a circle SVG element). Is there any work around to use this attribute (and others) you are using right now?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For filter you can use CSS styles as workaround, like this:

```
const style = {
  filter: `url(#${app || 'default'})`
}
```

And the returning component...

`return  <circle cx={50 * idx} cy={50 * idx} r='25' style={style} />`

If you only want to filter you can use plain CSS. Thus, add it to React props.

Comment: Yes it worked! But still only for the "filter" attribute. Maybe there are other workarounds for other attributes that do not work. Edit if you find out anything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

React *does* support SVG. The issue you've linked to has been fixed. In some cases the JSX attribute will be different to the HTML attribute, e.g. `xlinkHref` instead of `xlink:href`. It should not be necessary to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

In the code above, it looks as if you're simply using the wrong variable. You want this instead:

```
filter={`url(#${icon})`}
```

Comment: Just edited. Yeah SVG is _partially_ supported (as in the link I shared). And the variable was wrong, but still is not the problem since `filter` attribute won't be rendered at all. Not even as `filter="url(#undefined)"`

Comment: It appears this has been fixed as of React 0.15.0: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/6243